# Publishing Error: System.AggregateException: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:moving' event

Tags: sxa, publishing

I am using sitecore 9 and SXA 1.7, whenever I try to publish my site, I get this error. I have tried publishing other individual items that my site depends on, like the templates,and I have narrowed it down to having this error when I try to publish a certain templates folder and any of its respective children specifically, lets call it "blogs".

Any ideas on what could be the cause of this exception would be great or how to solve it would be great. I've searched around for a while but I can't find anyone who got the same error and is using sitecore 9.

Here is the full error if it will help

> Job started: Publish to 'web'|#Exception:
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. ---> System.AggregateException: One or
>   more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the
>   'item:moving' event.    at
>   Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName,
>   Object[] parameters, EventResult result)    at
>   Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[]
>   parameters)    at Sitecore.Events.Event.DataEngine_MovingItem(Object
>   sender, ExecutingEventArgs`1 e)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseEvent[TArgs](EventHandler`1
>   handlers, Func`2 argsCreator)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseExecuting(Boolean&
>   cancelled)    at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.CanExecute()
>   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute()    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.MoveItem(Item item, Item
>   destination, SecurityCheck securityCheck)    at
>   Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.MoveItems.MoveTargetItem(Item
>   targetItem, ID destinationId, PublishItemContext context)    at
>   Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.MoveItems.ProcessItem(Item
>   sourceItem, Item targetItem, PublishItemContext context)    at
>   Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.MoveItems.Process(PublishItemContext
>   context)    at (Object , Object[] )    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)    at
>   Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.PublishItemPipeline.Run(PublishItemContext
>   context)    at
>   Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate
>   entry, PublishContext context, List`1& referrers, List`1& children)
>
>   at
>   Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate
>   entry, PublishContext context)    at
>   Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1
>   entries, PublishContext context)    at
>   Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate
>   entry, PublishContext context)    at
>   Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1
>   entries, PublishContext context)    at
>   Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.Process(PublishContext
>   context)    at (Object , Object[] )    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)    at
>   Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.PublishPipeline.Run(PublishContext
>   context)    at Sitecore.Publishing.Publisher.PublishWithResult()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method,
>   Object[] parameters, Object obj)    at
>   Sitecore.Jobs.JobRunner.RunMethod(JobArgs args)    at (Object ,
>   Object[] )    at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs
>   args)    at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String
>   pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)    at
>   Sitecore.Jobs.Job.DoExecute()    at
>   Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)

Comment: I got the same problem in all environments with Sitecore 9, Sxa 1.7
Currently, I disabled item:moving event, but I don't know if it cause any issue.

Comment: @HardyNguyen Did disabling the item remove the error though?

Comment: This is known issue and will be fixed in 1.8. I known that some customers have already reported this and our support will be creating hotfix for this. It would be the best if you would register new support ticket and maybe till that time they will already have the package with hotfix created.

Comment: @DawidRutkowski is there no current workaround at least to this? anything i can do to avoid the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a chat with the Support guys and looks like they already have a patch for it! It was created for 1.7 but according to them, it's also compatible with 1.7.1.

Here is the link for the patch: https://github.com/SitecoreSupport/Sitecore.Support.13144/releases/tag/1.7.0.0

Comment: i'll try it out, thank you for your help :)

Comment: it worked! thanks again :) just download the zip file, extract it, and copy its contents into the sitecore website folder you have, agreeing to overwriting the 2 files (if asked to do so), and do an iisreset, it'll work

Comment: It consists of 1 dll file and 1 config file.

Comment: I tried adding config file and dll file in my sitecore instance 9.0 update 2 but still get the same issue.
 

So then i tried to get the source code from https://github.com/sitecoresupport/Sitecore.Support.13144/releases and tried to build the dll but it gives me reference error with the following dlls which i can not find anywhere in nuget as well as my local machine web site root.
Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Abstractions.dll
Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Common.dll
Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite.dll